# Is there a templating language similar to Razor for pure Javascript applications?

Tags: javascript, razor, rythm

I'm in love with razor templates in .NET MVC 3. Is there anything close for javascript?

I'd be looking for something where I could use something like this:

```
@if(bla)
{
  <span>my html</span>
}
```

I already know something similar exists fo Java. What about Javascript? ;)

Comment: might want to checkout handlebars - http://handlebarsjs.com/ not exactly the same, it is a templating engine and doesn't support 'true' conditionals but has conditions that act upon data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) is what you're looking for.

You can do conditionals like this

```
<!-- ko if: $data === app.viewModel.admin.home.paging.page() -->
    <span data-bind="html: $data"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Source: [Does conditional logic work under the default knockout.js 2.0 template engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810777/does-conditional-logic-work-under-the-default-knockout-js-2-0-template-engine)